# Toggling rpi3 GPIO pins with a Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am a novice programmer.  I learned to code in Basic back in the Commodore 64 days.  Recently, I purchased a Raspberry Pi 3 and an 8-channel relay board and am writing a script in Python 3.x to control the relay board via the GPIO pins.  The script I have written works but I suspect it is not very efficient.  Any critiques or advice would be appreciated.

That being said, I would like to alter the script to toggle the pin's state when it's number is input.  Currently, when the user inputs a number, the pin becomes active for a few seconds then shuts down.  I would like for the pin to remain active until the user chooses the same number again.  I am fairly certain I could code something that will work but, my initial thoughts would be to start another loops that would turn it off again.  Not sure if that makes sense but I AM sure it would not be an elegant or efficiently coded solution.

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO   # import the GPIO Library
import time   # import system time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  # set pin numbering 

PinList = [2, 3, 4, 17, 27, 22, 10, 9]   # init list with pin numbers

SleepTime = 4    # set sleep delay variable

for i in PinList:       # loop through pins and set mode and state to 'low' 
GPIO.setup(i, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.output(i, GPIO.HIGH)

# Get user input, turn on the appropriate GPIO pin, pause, then turn it off.

    while True:
    choice = input("\nEnter a number between 1 and 8.\nEnter 0 to exit:  ")
    if choice == '0':
    break

    if choice == '1':
    print("You chose 1")
    GPIO.output(9, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(SleepTime)
    GPIO.output(9, GPIO.HIGH)

    elif choice == '2':
    print("You chose 2")
    GPIO.output(10, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(SleepTime)
    GPIO.output(10, GPIO.HIGH)

    elif choice == '3':
    print("You chose 3")
    GPIO.output(22, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(SleepTime)
    GPIO.output(22, GPIO.HIGH)

    elif choice == '4':
    print("You chose 4")
    GPIO.output(27, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(SleepTime)
    GPIO.output(27, GPIO.HIGH)

    elif choice == '5':
    print("You chose 5")
    GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(SleepTime)
    GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)

    elif choice == '6':
    print("You chose 6")
    GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(SleepTime)
    GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)

    elif choice == '7':
    print("You chose 7")
    GPIO.output(3, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(SleepTime)
    GPIO.output(3, GPIO.HIGH)

    elif choice == '8':
    print("You chose 8")
    GPIO.output(2, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(SleepTime)
    GPIO.output(2, GPIO.HIGH)

    else:
    print("\nThat is not a valid input.")

print ("\n  Quit")

GPIO.cleanup()  # Reset GPIO pin settings
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Python for my Pi coding, but I am quite familiar with the language. Here's a quickly drummed up example that cleans up your code quite a bit, and gets you the desired action; the pin will remain in it's last state until selected a second time, which will toggle it to it's opposite state.

Instead of using a bunch of `if/else` statements, we simply map all of the pins to the selection number in a dictionary, and throw the user's selection into the dict as a key to get back out the BCM pin number and act on it directly. You'll almost certainly want to add in further error checking (if a user sends in an alpha char for example):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

pins = { 
    1: 9,
    2: 10,
    3: 22,
    4: 27,
    5: 17,
    6: 4,
    7: 3,
    8: 2
}

for pin in pins.values():
    GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.OUT)

while True:
    choice = int(input("\nenter a pin number (0 to exit): "))

    if choice == 0:
        exit()

    if choice not in pins.keys():
        print("\ninvalid selection...\n")
        continue

    pin = pins[choice]

    print("working on pin {}\n".format(pin))

    GPIO.output(pin, not GPIO.input(pin))

    print("pin {}: status {}\n".format(pin, GPIO.input(pin)))

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Great suggestion!  Very elegant and efficient.  I did have 2 problems.  For some reason my Pi did not like the 'exit()' command.  I exchanged it for 'break' and it worked fine.  Secondly, it bombed when I selected '8' which was caused by a missing comma.  Works fine now.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm glad it was useful @Mekanik! I believe if you `import sys`, and then use `sys.exit()` you should get around the exit issue. Realistically though, `break` is likely better, that way the `cleanup()` will be called in all cases.